# Phonon calculations using Phonopy

Tags: vasp, phonons, phonopy, dfpt

Hello everyone: I am doing phonon calculations to plot Helmholtz free energy against temperature. I am using Phonopy with DFPT method. Now I am done but appears if I want to use Phonopy-qha I need the thermal-properties of each of the e-v.dat data. Phonopy says I am supposed to compute the thermal-properties of each of the volumes specified in the e-v.dat file. Please how do I go about this? Do I need to do a new phonon calculations which is very expensive or I can still use the data from the DFPT? My aim is to plot Free energy against temperature with phonons and without phonons. Thank you.

Comment: The popular example https://github.com/phonopy/phonopy/tree/develop/example/Cu-QHA of using phonopy-qha applies the supercell method not the DFPT method. In general and in the supercell method, you can build the e-v.dat file by yourself by looking at the values of volume/energy for each of the seperate cell calculations you had. In DFPT, those values shall be written somewhere in the vasprun.xml. So, you need to open the vasprun.xml file of your DFPT calculation and search for the corresponding values of 'volume' and 'E_0'. The thermal_properties.yaml file can be obtained with -t option.

Comment: @JaafarMehrez I am not looking for the e-v data. I have it already. Rather, phonopy-qha requires that I compute thermal properties corresponding to each of the volumes I have in the e-v.dat file. The e-v.dat file was computed outside phonon calculations. Using DFPT, we only get one poscar file unlike the finite displacement method where you have a lot of poscars each corresponding to the displacement. In that way you could easily compute for each of the poscars. But in my case I used DFPT and I can only compute one thermal properties for the postcar-unitcell.

Comment: I am aware of this issue that's why I am not sure whether you can perform what you are looking for depending on DFPT, but as a hint, DFPT involves the calculation of the dynamical matrix, which involves evaluating the second derivative of the total energy with respect to atomic displacements. Thus, I think those POSCARS or displacements should be written somewhere in the vasprun.xml. Will you be able to get the thermal properties if you could find those new atomic positions? I am interested in this as well and would like to hear back from you if you get the answer for that.